# How to use the plural of a glossary entry?

Tags: glossaries

For example, my glossary entry is:

```
\newglossaryentry{WAV}
{
    name=WAV, 
    description={WAVEform audio file format}
}
```

If i write `\gls{WAVs}` I get an **error**. How can I fix this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to define plural form at all if it's only adding an 's' but in general something like this should solve the problem

```
\newglossaryentry{WAV}
{
    name=WAV, 
    description={WAVEform audio file format}
    plural=WAVs
}
```

You can make it appear plural using `\glspl{WAV}`.